# In lua, array sub element

Tags: arrays, lua, lua-table

In Lua,
I want to select the parts of the array.
The below example selects from the second elements

```
a = { 1, 2, 3}
print(a)

b = {}
for i = 2, table.getn(a) do
  table.insert(b, a[i])
end
print(b)
```

In python a[1:] works.
Does Lua have the similar syntax?

Comment: Please do not use ```table.getn(t)``` it I'd bad practice, please use ```#t```

Answer (score 7):

Lua does not have similar syntax. However, you can define your own function to easily wrap this logic up.

```
local function slice (tbl, s, e)
    local pos, new = 1, {}
    
    for i = s, e do
        new[pos] = tbl[i]
        pos = pos + 1
    end
    
    return new
end

local foo = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }
local bar = slice(foo, 2, 4)

for index, value in ipairs(bar) do
    print (index, value)
end
```

Note that this is a *shallow* copy of the elements in `foo` to `bar`.

---

Alternatively, in Lua 5.2 you could use `table.pack` and `table.unpack`.

```
local foo = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }
local bar = table.pack(table.unpack(foo, 2, 4))
```

Although the manual has this to say:

> table.pack (···)
>
> Returns a new table with all parameters stored into keys 1, 2, etc. and with a field "n" with the total number of parameters. Note that the resulting table may not be a sequence.

---

While Lua 5.3 has [`table.move`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-table.move):

```
local foo = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }
local bar = table.move(foo, 2, 4, 1, {})
```

---

And finally, most would probably opt to define some kind of OOP abstraction over this.

```
local list = {}
list.__index = list

function list.new (o)
    return setmetatable(o or {}, list)
end

function list:append (v)
    self[#self + 1] = v
end

function list:slice (i, j)
    local ls = list.new()
    
    for i = i or 1, j or #self do
        ls:append(self[i])
    end
    
    return ls
end

local foo = list.new { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }
local bar = foo:slice(2, 4)
```